# Can't restore a file from duplicity

Tags: ubuntu, duplicity

When I try to recover a single file from the backup, it creates an unformatted file

sudo duplicity --file-to-restore prueba2.txt file:///copia ~/escritorio/

the command works but returns the following file with no extension

I tried another syntax but still dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right, that is not well documented but correct.

if you give a **file, not a folder** to `--file-to-restore` the restore target will be interpreted as such. meaning

`duplicity --file-to-restore prueba2.txt file:///copia ~/escritorio/` will restore **as a file** called `~/escritorio` ignoring the trailing slash possibly overwriting an existing folder by that name (if empty or `--force` is given).

`duplicity --file-to-restore folder/folder2 file:///copia ~/escritorio/` will restore **as a folder** called `~/escritorio` overwriting an exisiting folder by that name (if empty or `--force` is given).